# Android service not working

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to call a service class to update the value of a variable from my widget but it doesn't ever seem to get to the service class. I've had a look at some examples and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I don't really know very much about services yet. All help appreciated.

Service class

```
public class toggleMonitoringService extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d("Me","creating service");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId, int something) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String toggle = intent.getExtras().getString("Toggle");
        Log.d("Me","Toggle : " + toggle);
        if (toggle.equals("app1"))
        {
            UpdateWidgetService.monitorApp1 = !UpdateWidgetService.monitorApp1;
        }
        else if (toggle.equals("app2"))
        {
            UpdateWidgetService.monitorApp2 = !UpdateWidgetService.monitorApp2;
        }


        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, something);
        return 0;
    }



}
```

Where I set up the intent and pending intent to handle the button click from the widget

```
    Intent monitor1toggle = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),toggleMonitoringService.class);
    monitor1toggle.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    monitor1toggle.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,allWidgetIds);
    monitor1toggle.putExtra("Toggle","app1");
    PendingIntent monitor1 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0 , monitor1toggle,0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.firstappstatus, monitor1);
```

Comment: have u added the service in menifest xml

Comment: Added service class to ur manifest file?

Comment: I hadn't but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try start service manually, wihtout using `PendingIntent`.
Better way is not to start service each time you need to do something, but to start it once, bind to it and use common method calls when you need something from the service.

For your example even a simple `Thread` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I need it to be called when the button on the widget is pressed and setting up a thread to do it would be a bit overkill, because the button won't be pressed too often but it does need to be there. As it is the service isn't even starting which is what I need help with

Comment: @Cob50nm using service for setting a boolean is overkill not less, I mention thread because that's simplier way to do something "on side" and less expensive than starting a new service